# Как с помощью GTest отслеживать внутренние вызовы?

Tags: c++, gtest

```
template<class It>
void verify_range(const It& first, const It& last){
  if constexpr(simple_it<It>){
    verify_range_simple(first, last);
  }

  if constexpr(checked_it<It>){
    verify_range_checked(first, last);
  }
}
```

В тесте я хочу убедиться, что для итераторов были вызваны соответствующие функции.

```
TEST(A, A){
  checked_iterator<int> a;
  checked_iterator<int> b;

  verify_range(a, b);

  EXPECT_EQ(counter_for_checked, 1);
  EXPECT_EQ(counter_for_simple, 0);
}

TEST(B, B){
  simple_iterator<int> a;
  simple_iterator<int> b;

  verify_range(a, b);

  EXPECT_EQ(counter_for_checked, 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(counter_for_simple, 1);
}
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Мне нужно решение, которое не делало бы лишних действий не в тестах. Т.е. вот такое решение мне не подходит:

```
template<class It>
void verify_range(const It& first, const It& last){
  static int counter_for_checked = 0;
  static int counter_for_simple = 0;

  if constexpr(simple_it<It>){
    ++counter_for_simple;
    verify_range_simple(first, last);
  }

  if constexpr(checked_it<It>){
    ++counter_for_checked;
    verify_range_checked(first, last);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133735/check-if-the-function-has-been-called-in-gtest#comment61806827_37133735

Comment: По идее, счетчик должен быть внутри `verify_range_simple`